# Jersey 2 injection source for multipart formdata

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I had a method:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces( {"text/xml"})
public Response processForm(
    @FormDataParam("myparam") InputStream is,
    @FormDataParam("myparam") FormDataContentDisposition detail)
```

which worked fine with Jersey 1.x.

I'm upgrading to 2.0 m11.

Now I get the following error:

```
12/01/2013 11:15:04 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0-m11 2012-12-21 12:34:15...
12/01/2013 11:15:04 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors processErrors
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected:
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.plutext.FileUpload.processForm(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish
.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.
```

I found  http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1413 and commit http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/commits/archive/2012-09/message/126 which seems relevant, but its not obvious to me what to do to fix the problem.

**UPDATED**

I made a servlet, which runs in Tomcat before org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize:

```
public class Jersey2Init extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger jul = Logger.getLogger(Jersey2Init.class
        .getName());

    static {    
        System.out.println("\n\nrunning Jersey2Init\n\n");

        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig1 = new ResourceConfig(XFormService.class);
        resourceConfig1.registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(jul, true));
        resourceConfig1.register(MultiPartFeature.class);       

        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig2 = new ResourceConfig(AssembleService.class);
        resourceConfig2.registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(jul, true));
        resourceConfig2.register(MultiPartFeature.class);       
    }
}
```

It is definitely running first:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\Foo-Services.war


running Jersey2Init


18/01/2013 9:09:51 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0-m11 2012-12-21 12:34:15...
18/01/2013 9:09:52 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors processErrors
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected:
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to enable MultiPart feature on your application. Enabling this feature injects necessary message body readers, writers to your Jersey 2 application. Here is how you register them:

#### On the server-side (http-server):

```java
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(MultiPartResource.class);
resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

#### On the server-side (servlet deployment):

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // register resources and features
        classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        classes.add(MultiPartResource.class);
        classes.add(LoggingFilter.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

#### web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.aruld.jersey.multipart.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### On the client-side:

```java
final ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient(clientConfig);
```

I put together an end-to-end Jersey 2 MultiPart sample in Github [here](https://github.com/aruld/jersey2-multipart-sample).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear answer.  I wonder though where to put the ResourceConfig stuff when running Tomcat. Putting it in a static initializer in the service class itself (MultiPartResource in your example) is no good. In a dummy servlet with load-on-startup 1, executed before the jersey servlet?

Comment: How would I do that when using autodiscovery?

Answer (score 30):

I was trying to use Jersey 2 for fileupload. I wanted to avoid creating a custom Application or ResourceConfig class to enable MultiPart. It is not well documented, but if you want to add Multipart functionality, all you have to do is add this to your Jersey servlet config in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

As you can see, I also added a loggingfilter.

Comment: Thanks - that's by far the simplest approach when the rest of the app is using auto configuration.

Answer (score 3):

And using an annotated application instance...

```
@ApplicationPath("restAPI")
public class ServiceApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public ServiceApplication() {
        register(JAXBContextResolver.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(ServiceApplication.class.getName()), true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Jersey 2.7 and was getting the same error. It resolved itself by upgrading to Jersey 2.9

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot I found you have to import `import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;` not `import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;` so that you can use `@FormDataParam`