# ResourceConfig and Application

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

What is the advantages of using ResourceConfig over Application(since ResourceConfig extends Application).

using ResourceConfig

```
   @ApplicationPath("/")
    public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
    super(MultiPartResource.class, MultiPartResource.class, MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
    }
```

using Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
// register resources and features
classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
classes.add(MultiPartResource.class);
classes.add(LoggingFilter.class);
return classes;
}
}
```

In the post [Jersey 2 injection source for multipart formdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288856/jersey-2-injection-source) @Arul Dhesiaseelan answered to add the MultiPartFeature to both to enable that feature on the server side.
Could someone explain.

Comment: See also [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45625925/2587435)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from the documentation: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html

"Compared to Application, the ResourceConfig provides advanced capabilities to simplify registration of JAX-RS components, such as scanning for root resource and provider classes in a provided classpath or a in a set of package names etc. All JAX-RS component classes that are either manually registered or found during scanning are automatically added to the set of classes that are returned by getClasses. "