# What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have seen a lot of Jersey tutorials that starts with something like

```
@ApplicationPath("services")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("com.abc.jersey.services");
    }
}
```

without explaining what exactly the `ResourceConfig` class is. So where can I find its documentation, usage, etc.? Googling for "jersey resourceconfig" does not yield any official doc.

Some of my questions about this class and its usage are:

- What things can I do inside the subclass of `ResourceConfig`?
- Do I need to register the subclass of `ResourceConfig` somewhere so that it can be found or is it automatically detected by Jersey?
- If the subclass is automatically detected what happens if I have multiple subclasses of `ResourceConfig`?
- Is the purpose of `ResourceConfig` the same as the `web.xml` file? If so what happens if I have both in my project? Does one of them take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Standard JAX-RS uses an [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) as its configuration class. [`ResourceConfig`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) *extends* `Application`.

There are three main ways (in a servlet container) to configure Jersey (JAX-RS):

1. With only web.xml
2. With both web.xml *and* an `Application/ResourceConfig` class
3. With only an `Application/ResourceConfig` class annotated with `@ApplicationPath`.

### With only web.xml

It is possible to configure the application in a standard JAX-RS way, but the following is specific to Jersey

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mypackage.to.scan</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Since Jersey runs in a servlet container, it is only right that the Jersey application runs as a servlet. The Jersey Servlet that handles incoming requests is the [`ServletContainer`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html). So here we declare it as the `<servlet-class>`. We also configure an `<init-param>` telling Jersey which package(s) to scan for our `@Path` and `@Provider` classes so it can register them.

Under the hood, Jersey will actually create a `ResourceConfig` instance, as that's what it uses to configure the application. Then it will register all the classes that it discovers through the package scan.

### With both web.xml and `Application/ResourceConfig`

If we want to programmatically configure our application with an `Application` or `ResourceConfig` subclass, we can do so with one change to the above web.xml. Instead of setting an init-param to scan for packages, we use an init-param to declare our `Application/ResourceConfig` subclass.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</servlet>
```

> **Note:** With Jersey 3.x (JakartaEE), you will be using the `param-name` - `jakarta.ws.rs.Application`.

```java
package com.example;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("com.abc.jersey.services");
    }
}
```

Here, we configure the `init-param` `javax.ws.rs.Application` with the fully qualified name of our `ResourceConfig` subclass. And instead of using the `init-param` that tells Jersey which package(s) to scan, we just use the convenience method `packages()` of the `ResourceConfig`.

We could also use the methods `register()` and `property()` to register resources and providers, and to configure Jersey properties. With the `property()` method, anything that can be configured as an `init-param`, can also be configured using the `property()` method. For instance instead of calling `packages()`, we could do

```
public JerseyApplication() {
    property("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
             "com.mypackage.to.scan");
}
```

### With only `Application/ResourceConfig`

Without a web.xml, Jersey needs a way for us to provide the servlet-mapping. We do this with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation.

```
// 'services', '/services', or '/services/*'
// is all the same. Jersey will change it to be '/services/*'
@ApplicationPath("services")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("com.abc.jersey.services");
    }
}
```

Here with the `@ApplicationPath`, it's just like if we configured the servlet mapping in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When using only Java code for configuration, there needs to be some way for Jersey to discover our configuration class. This is done with the use of a [`ServletContanerInitializer`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). This is something that was introduced in the Servlet 3.0 Specification, so we cannot use "Java only" configuration in earlier servlet containers.

Basically what happens is that the implementor of the initializer can tell the servlet container what classes to look for, and the servlet container will pass those classes to the initializer `onStartup()` method. In Jersey's implementation of the initializer, Jersey configures it to look for `Application` classes and classes annotated with `@ApplicationPath`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730471/2587435) for further explanation. So when the servlet container starts the application, Jersey's initializer will get passed our `Application/ResourceConfig` class.

### What things can I do inside the subclass of ResourceConfig

Just look at the [javadoc](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html). Its mostly just registration of classes. Not much else you need to do with it. The main methods you will be using are the `register()`, `packages()`, and `property()` methods. The `register()` method lets you manually register classes and instances of resources and providers manually. The `packages()` method, discussed earlier, lists the package(s) you want Jersey to scan for `@Path` and `@Provider` classes and register them for you. And the `property()` method allows you to set some [configurable properties](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) <sup>1</sup>.

The `ResourceConfig` is just a convenience class. Remember, it extends `Application`, so we could even use the standard `Application` class

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class JerseyApplication extends Application {

    private final Set<Class<?>> classes;
    private final Set<Object> singletons;

    public JerseyApplication() {
        // configure in constructor as Jersey
        // may call the getXxx methods multiple times

        this.classes = new HashSet<>();
        this.classes.add(MyResource.class);

        this.singletons = new HashSet<>();
        this.singletons.add(new MyProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return this.classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return this.singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                       "com.mypackage.to.scan");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

With a `ResourceConfig`, we would just do

```
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        register(MyResource.class);
        register(new MyProvider());
        packages("com.mypackages.to.scan");
    }
}
```

Aside from being more convenient, there are also a few thing under the hood that help Jersey configure the application.

### An SE Environment

All the examples above assume you are running in an installed server environment, e.g. Tomcat. But you can also run the app in an SE environment, where you run an embedded server and start the app from a `main` method. You will sometimes see these examples when searching around for info, so I want to show what that looks like, so that if you ever do come across this, you are not surprised and know how it differs from your setup.

So sometimes you will see an example like

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages("com.my.package");
config.register(SomeFeature.class);
config.property(SOME_PROP, someValue);
```

What is most likely happening here is that the example is using an embedded server, like Grizzly. The rest of the code to start the server might be something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("com.my.package");
    config.register(SomeFeature.class);
    config.property(SOME_PROP, someValue);

    String baseUri = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory
            .createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), config);
    server.start();
}
```

So in this example, there is a standalone server being started and the `ResourceConfig` is used to configure Jersey. The different here and from previous examples is that in this example, we are not extending the `ResourceConfig`, but instead just instantiating it. It wouldn't be any different if we were to do

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.my.package");
        register(SomeFeature.class);
        property(SOME_PROP, someValue);
    }
}

HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory
            .createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), new JerseyConfig());
```

Say you were going through some tutorial and it showed a configuration for a standalone app where they instantiate the `ResourceConfig`. But you are running your app in an installed servlet container and have been using the earlier configuration where you are extending the `ResourceConfig`. Well now you know what the difference is and what changes you need to make. I've seen people do some really weird stuff because they didn't understand this difference. For example I saw someone instantiating a `ResourceConfig` inside a resource class. So this is why I added this extra little piece; so you don't make the same mistake.

---

#### Footnotes

<sub>1. There are a number of different configurable properties. The link to the [`ServerProperties`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) are just some general properties. There are also different properties related to specific features. The documentation should mention these properties in the section of the docs related to that feature. For a complete list of *all* configurable properties, you can look at all the [Jersey constants](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/constant-values.html) and look for the ones where the string value starts with `jersey.config`. If you are using a web.xml, then you would use the string value as the `init-param` `param-name`. If you are using Java config (`ResourceConfig`), then you would call `property(ServerProperties.SOME_CONF, value)`</sub>

Comment: If you use the web.xml & ResourceConfig solution and you use Jersey 3.x - you need to set `jakarta.ws.rs.Application` as `param-name`!

Comment: Great answer. Just curious, where would we find the official docs on this? All the jersey links seem to be broken and point to a generic Jakarta homepage now.

Comment: @JesseBarnum https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html