# No injection source found for Multipart feature

Tags: maven, jersey, glassfish, jersey-2.0, multipart

when I try to deploy my maven project to Glassfish 5, I get the following error:

> [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.test.Resources.AccountResource.addProfilePicture(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.test.Resources.AccountResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1efcbc1f]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.test.Resources.AccountResource.addProfilePicture(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=profilePicture, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=profilePicture, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']. Please see server.log for more details.

This is the code which causes the troubles:

```java
@POST
@Path("addProfilePicture")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addProfilePicture(@FormDataParam("profilePicture") InputStream pic,
                                  @FormDataParam("profilePicture") FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition){



    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

According to similar answers, I should add the maven dependency and register the `MultiPartFeature`.

As you can see, I did both.

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        System.out.println("added multipart feature");
        classes.add(AccountResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

and here are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I already tried to change the `scope` to `provided` and used `ResourceConfig` instead of `Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the thing. You have two different application configurations: the web.xml and the `ApplicationConfig` class. These are to completely separate configurations, which are both valid all by themselves. The `ApplicationConfig` class is the one that registers the `MultiPartFeature`, but it seems like the configuration that is being used is the web.xml. I never really tested what happens when you have two different application configurations, but it seems like your web.xml is taking precedence. And in your web.xml, you are not configuring the `MultiPartFeature`.

If you want to just use the `web.xml`, then you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435) for how out can configure it.

You can however just delete the entire web.xml. This will cause the `ApplicationConfig` to kick it. But notice the two differences: the `@ApplicationPath` on the `ApplicationConfig` acts like the `url-mapping` in the web.xml. So if you delete the web.xml, then the base path will just be `/` (or nothing) instead of the `/webapi` like you have in the web.xml

If you decide the delete the web.xml, I suggest you use `ResourceConfig` instead of `Application`. You can get some good information about this class and different configuration possibilities in this post from [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)

Comment: i deleted the web.xml and it works. Thanks Paul, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @JakobHerk No worries, glad to help.

Comment: Couple other pointers: 1) All your Jersey and (Servlet) dependencies should be in a provided scope since Glassfish already has them. 2) You are using a very old version of the Servlet API, and should upgrade it. I think it should be [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0). But still it should be a provided scope