# REST services fail with when using multipart_form_data in Jesery 2 on Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I have several other services that are working, but they would fail if i include the below method to upload a file:

```
@POST
@Path("/image2")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(fileDetails.getFileName());
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

[image]

Without the above method, other services work normally.

[image]

Here's my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <display-name>Talent Core</display-name>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Connection,Host,authorization</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <resource-env-ref>
     <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
     <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
 </web-app>
```

Environment:

- Jdk 8
- Tomcat 9

I tried as suggested here [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653012/multipart-form-data-no-injection-source-found-for-a-parameter-of-type-public-ja/30656345) but the same error.

Comment: Try to use one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435) configuration options for your app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this post might be applicable:

> [Why would “java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.” appear deploying Jersey app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112971/421195)
>
> In my case, I had a Jersey POST resource for file uploads. The
>   resource specified the parameter:
>
> ```
> @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file
> ```
>
> and consumed
>
> ```
> MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
> ```
>
> To fix the issue, I had to add the following to the Jersey REST
>   configuration in my web.xml file:
>
> ```
> <init-param>
>     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
>     <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
> </init-param>
> ```

---

ORIGINAL PROBLEM: HTTP 500 doing file upload under Tomcat/Jersey: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.`

SOLUTION: Add `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature` to web.xml.

NEW PROBLEM: `404- Not Found`

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Step into the debugger, and see if your code is even getting to `uploadImage()`.
2. If it is, print the filename and filepath from `fileDetails` to System.out.  Make sure that fileDetails isn't null, and that the file actually exists.
3. Otherwise, set a breakpoint in the code that's calling "uploadImage()", and make sure it's passing a valid filename and filepath to upload.

Please post back what you find.

Comment: I'm getting a 404- Not Found after including this `<servlet> <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name> <init-param> <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name> <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value> </init-param> </servlet>`

Comment: I tried as suggested..  i added sysouts but nothing prints. None of the services work if i have the `@FormDataParam` method. If i comment all services work normally.

Comment: Sigh... Statements like "Nothing prints" and "None of the services work" are unhelpfully vague.  I believe the original problem, "HTTP 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context." is resolved (by adding "MultiPartFeature" to web.xml).  Correct?  I assume invoking /image2 is still causing "HTTP 404- Not Found", correct?  Q: Are you using an IDE (for example, Eclipse)?  Have you tried the Eclipse debugger?  NEXT STEP (if the logs and if the Eclipse debugger don't help): write an [MCVE].

Comment: I have several other services (cruds - get,post), and they all work without including the imageUpload method. If i enable/uncomment it, then none of the other services work. That's what i meant. I'm building a WAR file and deploying it to Tomcat manually so not sure if debugging will work. Tomcat not running via IDE. I'm trying to do debug where this is missing by adding one method/param at a time now. Will update here if i can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked. I was using `web.xml` to register the class and for somereason that was not working. I changed to use Application instead of web.xml

Added a new class **`ApplicationConfig`** under root (/tf-core/src/main/java/com/tf/core):

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

@ApplicationPath("service") // set the path to REST web services
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
  public ApplicationConfig() {
    packages("com.tf.core").register(MultiPartFeature.class);
  }
}
```

**Servlet class** (at /tf-core/src/main/java/com/tf/core/servlet):

```
@POST
@Path("/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseBean uploadImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) {
    System.out.println(fileDetails.getFileName());
    ...
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Full example on [Github](https://github.com/ksurendra/java-examples/tree/master/java-jersey-rest-upload-files)