# Cannot implement simple file upload in Jersey- HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I have a problem with the uploading file in the JAX/jersery/tomee configuration. When I put Tomcat instead of TomEE everything works fine. I add MultipartFeater to the web.xml file, I tried to add it to the file from which I extend both Application and ResourceConfig. I have tried several things which I found on the internet but have not found a solution.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/mb-portal-service/api/v1")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        packages("org.ftc");
        //.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
       /* this.register(MultiPartFeature.class);*/
        /*this.register(UploadApiImpl.class);*/
        /*this.packages("org.ftc.*");*/
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.ftc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom

```
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.ftc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mb-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mb-service</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>mb-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.63</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--sssssssss-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-jwt-auth-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

UploadApiImpl.java

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@Path("/admin/upload")
@RequestScoped
public class UploadApiImpl {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream in,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition info) throws IOException {

        File upload = new File(info.getFileName());

        if (upload.exists()){
            String message = "file: " + upload.getName() + " already exists";
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(message).build();
        } else {
            Files.copy(in, upload.toPath());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(){

            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

In postman I send a file in the form-data part, the header is multipart / form-data.

I get an error org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper.toResponse javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Look at the exception. The packaging says that you are using CXF and NOT Jersey.

Comment: Ok, which package should I use in dependency, and which should I delete?

Comment: Remove the `@ApplicationPath` from your Application class and use the second configuration option in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435). The `@ApplicationPath` causes CXF (TomEE's JAX-RS implementation) to take over as it's a standard JAX-RS way of configuring an application. Tomcat has no JAX-RS support out of the box, that's why Jersey works fine in that environment.