# No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response - Jersey - MultiPartFeature

Tags: rest, jersey, jetty, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm creating a web service with Jersey and Jetty Embedded with no web.xml file. It is very simple, It receive a binary file by a POST from a HTML form. It seems I didn't register the MultiPart Feature properly because When I try to use it with HTML form I get this error :

*

> WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   org.multipart.demo.ReceiveFile.postMsg(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition)
>   throws java.lang.Exception at index 0. 2016-02-09
>   21:49:59.916:WARN:/:qtp1364335809-16: unavailable
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation
>   of the application resource model has failed during application
>   initialization.|[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of
>   type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   org.multipart.demo.ReceiveFile.postMsg(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition)
>   throws java.lang.Exception at index 0.;
>   source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST,
>   consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[text/plain],
>   suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0,

- I was looking for the solution for weeks, I have read all question related to this error on StackOverflow, for instance:

[MULTIPART_FORM_DATA: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653012/multipart-form-data-no-injection-source-found-for-a-parameter-of-type-public-ja)

[Jersey 2 injection source for multipart formdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288856/jersey-2-injection-source-for-multipart-formdata)

They didn't help me because Im not using web.xml

I have 3 classes 
- ReceiveFile.class (try to receive the POST)
- resourceConfig.class (try to register the MultiPart feature)
- JettyServer.class (create server instance)

ReceiveFile.class

```
package org.multipart.demo;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;



@Path("/resources")
public class ReceiveFile 
{

        @POST
        @Path("/fileUpload")
        @Produces("text/plain")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public Response postMsg (
                @FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream,
                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws Exception {


                    Response.Status respStatus = Response.Status.OK;




                    return Response.status(respStatus).build();
                    }

}
```

resourceConfig.class

```
package org.multipart.demo;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


    /**
     * Registers the components to be used by the JAX-RS application  
     *
     */
@ApplicationPath("/resources/fileUpload")
public class resourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

     /**
        * Register JAX-RS application components.
        */  

        public resourceConfig(){
            register(ReceiveFile.class);    
            register(JettyServer.class);
            register(MultiPartFeature.class);
            //packages("org.glassfish.jersey.media", "com.mypackage.providers");


        }

}
```

JettyServer.class

```
package org.multipart.demo;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;


public class JettyServer
{
    //   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UploadFile.class.getName()); 


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("org.multipart.demo");

    Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);

    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();

    // Configure the ResourceHandler. Setting the resource base indicates where the files should be served out of.
    // In this example it is the current directory but it can be configured to anything that the jvm has access to.
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "./index.html" , "./html/FileUpload.html"  });
    resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

    //Jersey ServletContextHandler
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ReceiveFile.class);
    resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = servletContextHandler.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*" );
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.multipart.demo");

    // Add the ResourceHandler to the server.
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, servletContextHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
    jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}


}
```

the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org</groupId>
  <artifactId>multipart.demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>multipart.demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
    <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I See three different `ResourceConfig`s in your codebase, but *none* of them are actually used for the application. So the `MultiPartFeature` is never register, which is what is causing the error. You have a few options on how to use a `ResourceConfig` in your case.

1. You can instantiate the `ServletContainer`, passing in the `ResourceConfig` instance. Unfortunately, there is no `ServletContextHolder#addServlet(Servlet)` method, but there is a `ServletContextHolder#addServlet(ServletHolder)` method, so we need to wrap the `ServletContainer` in a `ServletHolder`

   ```
   ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
   servletContextHolder.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");
   ```
2. With the above option, you can use a local instance or a subclass, but if you only have a subclass, like your first bit of code, then you add a servlet init param, that specifies the `ResourceConfig` subclass.

   ```
   ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
   ServletHolder jerseyServlet = servletContextHandler.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*" );
   jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.multipart.demo");
   jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, resourceConfig.class.getCanonicalName());
   ```

   Notice the last call where I set the application class name.
3. Without using a `ResourceConfig`, you could just register the `MulitPartFeature` with an init param

   ```
   jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES, MultiPartFeature.class.getCanonicalName());
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works. I really appreciate your help